# Can we access web elements of bank websites like ICICI, HDFC, SBI etc for automation using selenium Webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, iframe, webdriver, ui-automation

I am trying to automate bank website by accessing it's web elements of forms like username,contact number, email etc. But when I am trying to run , I am not able to access it's web elements as it is failing with exception "unable to locate an element" , let me know how we can access it .

[icicibank.com/Personal-Banking/loans/personal-loan/index.page](http://icicibank.com/Personal-Banking/loans/personal-loan/index.page)

Code:

```
WebElement firstName = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"firstNameId\"]")); 
WebElement lastName = driver.findElement(By.id("lastNameId"));
```

Comment: Some code example?[html + java]

Comment: I don't see any difference from the normal websites. Please edit your question and specify the problem. Code, HTML, links etc.

Comment: Why to copy try creating your own there are so many tutorial available in the web.

Comment: sample url : https://www.icicibank.com/Personal-Banking/loans/personal-loan/index.page

Comment: I tried to access webelement using xpath, name, id fields , but not able to locate while running them.

Comment: WebElement firstName = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"firstNameId\"]"));
WebElement lastName = driver.findElement(By.id("lastNameId"));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your element is inside `iframe`. You have to switch to it before you can locate element:

```
WebElement iframe = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe"));
driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);
```

then you can locate your element as usual:

```
WebElement firstName = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='firstNameId']")); 
WebElement lastName = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='lastNameId']"));
```

After you will be done with content inside `iframe`, you have to switch back to default content like this:

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

***PS:*** also I would use `WebDriverWait` like this:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.icicibank.com/Personal-Banking/loans/personal-loan/index.page");

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id='myDivAdd']/a[2]"))).click(); // dismiss popup

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe"))); // switch to iframe

WebElement firstName = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id='firstNameId']")));
firstName.click();
firstName.sendKeys("first name");

WebElement lastName = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id='lastNameId']")));
lastName.click();
lastName.sendKeys("last name");

driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

`WebDriverWait` will wait at least 10 seconds until `ExpectedConditions` will be satisfied and only then perform an action.

***Note:*** you have to add some imports:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
```

More information about `WebDriverWait` can be found in the [documentation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html).

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to your questions and one technical part got answered that your element was in an iframe so your automation code was not able to find it.

Second part of your question ( when you list so many banks ) is about legality and if that specific bank allows it. The general rule of thumb is - Selenium is for automated testing of a web based application that you are officially working on ( your own app, your organization's etc etc. ). So in my opinion, if you are not authorized by these banks then you shouldn't do it.

If not illegal then at least there is a chance of user id / account being blocked since most big companies employ bot detection algorithms. It is good if they stop you at your very initial request ( & only your IP is blocked ) but if you are allowed to move on till entering id & password etc ..then its too risky for you. These websites are designed for human use and automation can cause denial of service attacks ( including plenty of other types of attacks as well ) so most organizations detect and block such requests.